# What does the offset parameter in BeginDraw() mean,and how to use it?

Tags: c++11, windows-8, directx-11, direct2d

In [ISurfaceImageSourceNative::BeginDraw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848323.aspx)
we can see a parameter:offset, MSDN said it receives the point (x,y) offset of the surface that will be drawn into.But I don't know if it represents upper-left of the surface or the lower-right corner.And what's the meaning that it appears here.How to use it.

Regards& Thanks
halcyons

Comment: Although there is no explicit words in the Document, as my experience, the offset always related to the top-left corner of a rectangle area.

Comment: @zdd hi,I know you.I'm chinese too.Thank you for your reply.

Comment: As is "traditional" to drawing functions, it's the top-left corner. I've also found this which uses the offset after retreiving it from `BeginDraw()`, maybe it helps --> http://www.tuicool.com/articles/JbMfyy

Answer (score 1):

The offset value represents a 2D offset (x = right, y = down) which the app should apply prior to rendering to the surface.  For example, in order to draw a point at the logical location (A,B) relative to the origin (top-left) of the SurfaceImageSource, the point should be drawn at the location (A+offset.x, B+offset.y) on the IDXGISurface.

For an example of how to properly draw using SurfaceImageSource, check out the [Magazine](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Magazine-Sample-2a657289) sample on MSDN.